# Update list of displayed components on deletion in React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

in the beginning on my path with React I'm creating simple to-do app where user can add/remove task which are basically separate components.

I create tasks using:

```
addTask(taskObj){
    let tasksList = this.state.tasksList;
    tasksList.push(taskObj);
    this.setState({tasksList : tasksList});
}
```

I render list of components (tasks) using following method:

```
showTasks(){
    return (
        this.state.tasksList.map((item, index) => {
            return <SingleTask
                taskObj={item}
                removeTask = {(id) => this.removeTask(id)}
                key = {index}/>;
        })
    );
}
```

method to remove specific task takes unique ID of task as an argument and based on this ID I remove it from the tasks list:

```
removeTask(uID){
  this.setState(prevState => ({
        tasksList: prevState.tasksList.filter(el => el.id != uID )
    }));
}
```

But the problem is, when I delete any item but the last one, it seems like the actual list of components is the same only different objects are passed to those components.

For example:
Lets imagine I have 2 created componentes, if I set state.Name = 'Foo' on the first one, and state.Name='Bar' on the second one. If I click on remove button on the first one, the object associated to this component is removed, the second one becomes first but it's state.Name is now 'Foo' instead of 'Bar'.

I think I'm missing something there with correct creation/removing/displaying components in react.

Edit:

Method used to remove clicked component:

```
removeCurrentTask(){
    this.props.removeTask(this.props.taskObj.id);
}
```

SingleTask component:

```
class SingleTask extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
        showMenu : false,
        afterInit : false,
        id: Math.random()*100
    }

    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

toggleMenu(){
    this.setState({showMenu : !this.state.showMenu, afterInit : true});
}

render(){
    return(
        <MDBRow>
            <MDBCard className="singleTaskContainer">

                <MDBCardTitle>
                    <div class="priorityBadge">

                    </div>
                </MDBCardTitle>
                <MDBCardBody className="singleTaskBody">
                    <div className="singleTaskMenuContainer">

                        <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
                            <i className="align-middle material-icons">menu</i>
                        </a>
                        <div className={classNames('singleTaskMenuButtonsContainer animated',
                            {'show fadeInRight' : this.state.showMenu},
                            {'hideElement' : !this.state.showMenu},
                            {'fadeOutLeft' : !this.state.showMenu && this.state.afterInit})}>
                            <a
                                title="Remove task"
                                onClick={this.props.removeTask.bind(null, this.props.taskObj.id)}
                                className={
                                    classNames(
                                        'float-right btn-floating btn-smallx waves-effect waves-light listMenuBtn lightRed'
                                        )
                                }
                            >
                                <i className="align-middle material-icons">remove</i>
                            </a>
                            <a  title="Edit title"
                                className={classNames('show float-right btn-floating btn-smallx waves-effect waves-light listMenuBtn lightBlue')}
                            >
                                <i className="align-middle material-icons">edit</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {this.props.taskObj.description}
                    <br/>
                    {this.state.id}
                    </MDBCardBody>
            </MDBCard>
        </MDBRow>
    );
}
```

}

Below visual representation of error, image on the left is pre-deletion and on the right is post-deletion. While card with "22" was deleted the component itself wasn't deleted, only another object was passed to it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, the solution was simpler than expected.

In

```
const showTasks = () =>  taskList.map((item, index) => (
        <SingleTask
            taskObj={item}
            removeTask ={removeTask}
            key = {item.id}
        />
        )
    )
```

I was passing map `index` as a key, when I changed it to `{item.id}` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In short, in the statement `tasksList.push(<SingleTask taskObj={taskObj} removeTask ={this.removeTask}/>);`, **`removeTask = {this.removeTask}` should become `removeTask = {() => this.removeTask(taskObj.id)}`**.

However, I would reconsider the way the methods `addTask` and `showTasks` are written. While the way you have written isn't wrong, it is semantically unsound. Here's what I would do:

```
addTask(taskObj){
    let tasksList = this.state.tasksList;
    tasksList.push(taskObj);
    this.setState({tasksList : tasksList});
}

showTasks(){
    return (
        this.state.tasksList.map((item, index) => {
            return <SingleTask
                       taskObj={item}
                       removeTask ={() => this.removeTask(item.id)}/>;
        })
    );
}
```

```js
const SingleTask = (task) => {
  const { taskObj } = task;
  return <div onClick={task.removeTask}>
    { taskObj.title }
  </div>
}

// Example class component
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    tasksList: [
      { id: 1, title: "One" },
      { id: 2, title: "Two" },
      { id: 3, title: "Three" },
      { id: 4, title: "Four" }
    ]
  }
  
  addTask = (taskObj) => {
    let tasksList = this.state.tasksList;
    tasksList.push(taskObj);
    this.setState({tasksList : tasksList});
  }
  
  showTasks = () => {
    return (
        this.state.tasksList.map((item, index) => {
          return <SingleTask
            key={index}
            taskObj={item}
            removeTask ={() => this.removeTask(item.id)}/>;
        })
    );
  }
  
  removeTask(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tasksList: prevState.tasksList.filter(el => el.id != id )
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div> {this.showTasks()} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately after your changes the result is the same.

Comment: I don't know where `removeCurrentTask` is called, so I've updated my solution with a code snippet, if it helps.

Comment: It is called like that: `<a
                                    title="Remove task"
                                    onClick={this.removeCurrentTask}
                                    className={
                                        classNames(
                                            'float-right btn-floating btn-smallx waves-effect waves-light listMenuBtn`

Anyway, result is the same.

Comment: I see. Then your original `removeTask = {this.removeTask}` should become `removeTask = {(id) => this.removeTask(id)}`. Try this.

Comment: I've made all the changes you suggested, but the result is still the same, component is not really deleting, only specific object in list. I've edited methods in original posts due to all changes.

Comment: Interesting. Please include debugging logs, errors, if any. I am curious if it is a platform-related issue. Does the above snippet run as expected?

Comment: I don't get any logs or errors. I've attached visual representation of my case in original post just to clarify my issue. It's hard to say if snipped runs as expected, since there is no any "inner components values" displayed, only new different object passed. Can you please add in SingleTask constructor something like 
`this.state={
            id: Math.random()*100
        }`
and display it so we can see what happens?

Comment: I see a disconnect. Can you please attach your `SingleTask` component?

Comment: SingleTask added in original post.

Comment: I see the issue now. This is discussed by [Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/). Try converting your `SingleTask` class to a functional component.